# How to speedup node joining process in cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have  a cluster 4 cassandra nodes. I have recently added a new node but data  processing is taking too long. Is there a way to make this process faster ?              [output of nodetool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qYDd.png)

Comment: How long is too long? Your cluster currently has 50-80TB of data per node so your joining node is going to be having it's share of this data streamed to it during bootstrap. That is going to take a long time.

Comment: New node joined cluster 6 days ago and so far data processed on it is 918gb. Is this normal behavior or is there any way we can make this faster ?

Answer (score 0):

Less data per node.  Your screenshot shows 80TB per node, which is insanely high.

The recommendation is 1TB per node, 2TB at most.  The logic behind this is bootstrap times get too high (as you have noticed). A good Cassandra ring should be able to rapidly recover from node failure.  What happens if other nodes fail while the first one is rebuilding?

Keep in mind that the typical model for Cassandra is lots of smaller nodes, in contrast to SQL where you would have a few really powerful servers. (Scale out vs scale up)

So, I would fix the problem by growing your cluster to have 10X - 20X the number of nodes.

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nosql-databases/FpcSJcN9Opw

Comment: the statistic could be incorrect - I remember that some C* versions had a bug that instead of updating the Load part, it was summing up with previous values, until you restart the node

Comment: 1 - 2 TB per node is only true for ext2/ext3. https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware

Comment: @PedroGordo That link only refers to max file size. Not rebuild times. The guidance I posted is true regardless of FS type.

Comment: I think your usage of the word "recommendation" is the problem here. Per recommendation, I picture an official recommendation, but what you refer is taken from a Google group's discussion, so it's premature to call it a recommendation.

Comment: I'm not questioning your rationale. It makes perfect sense. I'm just saying to be careful because I've recently seen problems happening because people assume that a recommendation somewhere on the internet is an official recommendation.

Comment: so its been approximately 2 week since data processing started and so far 20% of it is done. Does this mean it will take 10 weeks for data processing to finish or will it speed up as it gets closer to finish ?

Comment: @TashfeenShahzad In my experience it takes about a day to bootstrap a node with 2TB of data so you can extrapolate from that. The rate of data transfer is mostly linear, but there will be a lot of compactions at the end. However there are a lot of variables in there like disk/network performance that can affect the speed of bootstrapping. It really sounds like you need to take a step back and re-evaluate how your cluster is sized.